# How to make header align with bootstrap columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can we make the `layouts/header` align with the `col-md-9` & `col-md-3` so that the "P" in Personal Control Center is perfectly aligned with the panel below it and the downward arrow is perfectly aligned with the right edge of the sidebar?

I was able to do it via padding in the first picture, but I'd like it to align perfectly regardless of screen size. As you can see as I decreased the width of the browser the it becomes less aligned.

[image]
[image]

*In the last case the downward arrow should align with right edge of panel.

[image]

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Personal Control Center</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        <!-- Tells app to be mobile responsive -->
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
    <% end %>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <% if current_user.present? %>
        <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**bootstrap_customization.css.scss**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);

$body-bg:                         #2c3e50;
$font-family-sans-serif:          'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$navbar-height:                   45px;
$navbar-default-bg:               white;
$navbar-default-brand-color:      #A73A31;
$brand-primary:                   #000;
$jumbotron-bg:                    #FFFFFF;

@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';

/* link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #2E2E2E;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

.panel {
  border: none;
}

#sidebarheadingtop {
  padding-top: .1em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#sidebarheading {
  padding-top: .1em;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#sidebarsectiontop {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0em 0em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0em 0em;
  border-style: none;
}

#sidebarsection {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-style: none;
}

#sidebarsectionbottom {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-top-radius: 0px;
  border-style: none;
}

.nav-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 8em;
  padding-right: 8em;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

.center {
     text-align: center;
}

.navbar-brand {
     font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  &:hover {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

If I change the application code to this:

```html
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
                <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
                <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
            <% end %>
        <!-- Rest of the code here -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

I get this:

[image]

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a blindly guess, I think wrapping this:

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
<% end %>
```

inside of your `.container` like this would do the job:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
            <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
        <% end %>
    <!-- Rest of the code here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**==== update ====**

Find `.container` width and give this same width for your header wrapper and a `margin: 0 auto;`. Your header must have a wrapper already but I'm gonna create one here for you to understand:

```
<body>
    <div class="headerWrapper">
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
            <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-9">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <% if current_user.present? %>
        <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This goes to your CSS file:

```
.headerWrapper {
    width: 1200px; /* this is just a width size example, the value that goes here is the same of your body width */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Here's an [online example](http://jsfiddle.net/g4momzu6/)**

Comment: Sorry about that Chun. I updated my question. I forgot I tried that in the past. I show above what I got with it. Thanks for helping me in the right direction.

Comment: Chun do I add `.yourHeaderClass` under `container` and end after the first `<% end %>` of the code? And I'm a little confused by your update, I have this in container: `.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
}` You want me to add this code + `width: 1200px` to `.yourheaderclass`? Doing this doesn't seem to change anything?

Comment: do you have an online example where can I see this?

Comment: No. Am I confusing you?

Comment: Can you incorporate your answers with the code provided please?

Comment: I didn't use width with container class.

Comment: And we would need a way that wouldn't affect the navbar whitespace. Just the lettering. Whitespace should run across the page like first pic Chun.

Comment: without seeing your code in action it's hard to tell exactly what to modify. But I made my answer as clear as possible for you to understand and attached an online example. study the code from the example and apply it to your project

Comment: Thank you @Chun with your answer I got closer to the problem. Part of it was in my _header.html.erb file. I had to change this `<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" role="navigation">` to this `<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">` but now the white space doesn't continue to the right and left edge of the browser. You know how to do that?

Comment: I know I need to add something between  `.navbar { }` in css